# Compare single elements in a List<DataTable> to another List<DataTable>

Tags: c#, foreach, datatables, nested-loops, nested-lists

I am trying to track changes in a database by running a query pre-change and taking all of the database values and putting them into a DataTable.  Each row is put into its own DataTable, then the DataTables are added into a List<>.  The same process is run again after a user update is processed.  I end up with something like this:

```
|   | oldData<record "1"> | <record "2"> |  | newData<record "1"> | <record "2"> |
|:-:|:-------------------:|:------------:|::|:-------------------:|:------------:|
|   | record "1"          | record "2"   |  | record "1"          | record "2"   |
| a | 11330002            | 14740032     |  | 11330002            | 14740032     |
| b | null                | null         |  | E                   | E            |
| c | true                | true         |  | true                | true         |
| n | ...                 | ...          |  | ...                 | ...          |
```

I populate the List I use the below method pre-change to get oldData.  The user makes changes then part of the save, after the update/insert SQL statement runs I run the method again to get the post-change List newData.

```
public static List<DataTable> buildDataTable()
        {
            List<DataTable> JobNumberList = new List<DataTable>();

            string conString = "Data Source=nf-sql1;Initial Catalog=Tooling;Integrated Security=True";
            //List<DataTable> currentData = new List<DataTable>();
            DataTable currentData = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();
                foreach (string number in updateList)
                {
                    string selectQry = String.Format(@"SELECT *
                                            FROM Tooling.dbo.MoldingData
                                            WHERE JobNumber = {0}", number);

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQry))
                    {
                        command.Connection = con;

                        var resault = command.ExecuteReader();
                        currentData.Load(resault);
                    }

                    JobNumberList.Add(currentData);
                }
                return JobNumberList;
            }
        }
```

The goal is to create a record showing that null (oldData<1>.[b]) changed to E (newData<1>.[b]) and that null (oldData<2>.[b]) changed to E (newData<2>.[b]).  This will be but into a string that will be inserted into an SQL table. That will say something like:

> 11330002 record b changed from "null" to "E".

> 14740032 record b changed from "null" to "E".

I know I will need some sort of foreach loop to tunnel into each of the elements in the list with a nested foreach look to look at each of the elements in the DataTable.  I am struggling with getting the Datatable elements out to work with. As of right now, this is what I have.

```
foreach(DataTable oldListElement in oldData)
        {
            foreach(DataRow oldDTelement in oldListElement.Rows)
            {
                oldElement = oldDTelement[0].ToString();
                foreach(DataTable newListElelemt in newData)
                {
                    foreach(DataRow newDTelement in newListElelemt.Rows)
                    {
                        newElement = newDTelement[0].ToString();
                        if (!oldElement.Equals(newElement))
                        {
                            changeString = String.Format("{0} changed to {1}", oldElement, newElement);
                            Console.WriteLine(changeString);
                        }
```

Am I getting close?  This is baked into an application that is written in C#.

Comment: You don't need to do that. .NET already has a construct to hold multiple related DataTable objects, it's the DataSet. It already supports loading and comparing different row states in a DataTable, that's how a DataAdapter detects changes in a row and decides whether it needs to udpate, insert or delete a row. This isn't used for change tracking though because it's impractical for anything except the smallest databases.

Comment: You can use [DataTable.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataTable_Load_System_Data_IDataReader_System_Data_LoadOption_) to load new data into a DataTable without changing the Current data. You find the rows with changed state to detect changes. But again, databases have better mechanisms

Comment: For example, SQL Server's [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is a lightweight mechanism available in all versions and editions. [Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) keep track of changed rows and allow you to query for data at a specific point in time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is baked into a C# application.  The call that populates the oldData datatable and the newData datatable is the same SQL table.  It gets updated from user inputs.

Comment: Why are you using multiple `DataTable`s at all? It is a very heavyweight object for what it sounds like you are doing - why not use it as intended (`DataRow` for each database row) or use `Dictionary<,>` instead? Or even `List<List<object>>`? Also, please show your actual data structure / make a clearer picture...

Comment: @NetMage I'm not totally sure what you are talking bout with using a DataRow isn't the DataTable made of DataRows?  What more are you looking for in the data structure?  It is a List<DataTable>  The DataTable is filled with an SQL query that runs multiple times.  
The List<DataTable> "OldData" has the original information before a user edit.  This will show only one row of data in a DataTable per each list item.  An insert/ update SQL query runs and the List<DataTable> "NewData" has the new information in the same format as the OldData.
See edited post for hopefully more detail.

Comment: Why are you creating separate `DataTable`s for each one row result? Why not just load one `DataTable` with all the rows?